# What can I use as a static equivalent of Regex.Match(String, Int32)?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I use a permanent set of about eleven regular expressions to parse about 80k - 200k characters long strings. So far I just used `new Regex(@"blah")` in every place where I had to use [Match(String, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3583dcyh), [Replace(String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1) and [Replace(String, MatchEvaluator)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c).

But using these instance methods does not take advantage of the .NET's regular expressions cache. So I want to refactor my code to use static methods instead. The problem is I can't find a static equivalent of [Match(String, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3583dcyh).

I thought about just using [String.Substring(Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx) as appropriate but as far as I know it would allocate new String for me.

Do I have some other options?

Comment: Reading better your question maybe I have misunderstood your requirements... The problem is that you need to cache regexes or that you don't want to allocate a new string when you test a substring vs a regex?

Comment: @Gabber I just wanted to optimize my usage of Regex to reduce parsing time. I think your answer is good. I don't know why I didn't think of it. Perhaps I just read too much into [this post on MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/06/25/optimizing-regular-expression-performance-part-i-working-with-the-regex-class-and-regex-objects.aspx) and misunderstood the 'coupling process'.

Comment: If you have a common set of regex used on all strings, you can combine them, refactor them in 1/4 the space and  10 times the speed, into a single regex. http://regexformat.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a static instance of the 11 regexes and use it everywhere.

```
static Regex r= new Regex(...);
```

Or you can create a static singleton object which contains the regexes.

```
public MyStaticObject{
    private  Regex r1;
    private  Regex r2;

    public Regex R1{
        get{ return r1;}
    }
    //...
    private MyStaticObject instance;

    private MyStaticObject(){
        r1=new Regex(...);
    }

    public MyStaticObject GetInstance(){
        if(instance==null){
            instance= new MyStaticObject();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```